# Is there a way to change the VBA editor's own font?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, office365

In the red range, the font is different from the system font. The system font is `Microsoft YaHei UI`, but these parts of the font is `SimSun`.

Is there a way to change these parts of the font?

Or is there a way to beautify the VBA editor? VBA editor is not pretty.

---

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

Comment: No, there's no option for that.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Tools] -> [Options] -> [Editor Format] - in there you can set the fonts used for various elements of the VBE.

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant. I didn't want to change the font of the code, but the font of the editor's UI, because the font of the UI part is not uniform and it is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative solution.
VBA editor is ugly and doesn't have good intellisense. In addition, VBA is not fast.
These are reasons to prompt me to use Python+xlwings.

When I can use Python, beautiful editor UI and good intellisense I can get easily.

The most important, Excel operations will be faster.(numpy, pandas, etc can be used)

I am using [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) to make Python operating Excel.

From the pictures, do the same operation to Excel, `Python+xlwings` only need `4s`, but VBA needs `31s`.

So if someone can use a little Python, I recommend using `Python+xlwings` to operate excel.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can the python run the VBA code, like will it execute in the Excel application if run form python? Also which Python IDE are you using to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA editor UI is based on Windows system fonts. You need to edit the windows registry keys to make the required changes, see [How to change the default font in Windows® 8.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBxoR4TBdks)

Comment: But I do not know how to change the font, and I can not find out some results from Google about that. If you know, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Did you have a chance to play with system fonts like the video shows?

Comment: But I don't want to change system's font, system's font is the default "Microsoft YaHei UI," that is I want. In screen snapshots, that font is "SimSun."

Comment: Was the VBA editor's font changed when you did changes in the windows registry?